# Why are there kafka and brokers in the scdf trace shown in zipkin?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I have a spring cloud data flow environment created in kubernetes and a zipkin environment created as well. But when I look at the Dependencies in zipkin, I see that in addition to the application that exists in the stream, there is also a broker and kafka.
Is there anyone who can tell me why this is? And is there any way I can get broker and kafka to not show up.
[It's like this image shows](https://dataflow.spring.io/static/86a5c3fa2de90c83b92a358778fbc897/8d2ea/SCDF-stream-tracing-zipkinserver-dependencies.webp)

Answer (score 0):

That's because one of the brokers got resolved as being kafka (for example via special message headers) and the other didn't. It's either a bug in Sleuth or you're using an uninstrumented library.